# Difference between strstr() and strchr()

Tags: php

Do both the function return the same value?

```
<?php
echo "<br>".strstr("this is a test", "s");
echo "<br>".strchr("this is a test", "s");
?>
```

Is there any difference that i can't see?

Comment: You refereed link has very well explanation. Please read second answer.

Answer (score 0):

### strstr

> strstr — Find the first occurrence of a string

[PHP manual link for strstr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)

### strchr

> This function is an alias of: strstr().

[PHP manual link for strchr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strchr.php)

So, for your Question, the answer is "BOTH ARE SAME"

Comment: They are not "both the same". Not being pedantic, but specifically the end result is the same, but they are not to be considered the same from a dev POV as the alias may go away after deprecation period.

Answer (score -1):

You used `strstr()` which is an alias of `strchr()`, that's why it is just the same. But your reference compares `strchr()` and `strrchr()`, that's why you get a different result than from your reference

**EDIT**

Since you've edited your question. This is now my answer:

You used `strstr()` which is just an alias of `strchr()`, that's why it is just the same.